# AngularJS $scope.model is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS `$scope.model` is undefined when I initialize it via Javascript

```
<button ngf-select="upload($file)">Выбрать</button>
                <span id="photoSpan"></span>
                <input type="text"  id="photo" name="uploadPhoto" ng-model="uploadPhoto">
```

Here is my initialization code:

```
document.getElementById("photo").value = fileName;
                $("#photoSpan").text(resp.config.data.file.name);
                console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
```

So

```
createExpositionResource.photo = $scope.uploadPhoto;
        console.log('--------------'+$scope.uploadPhoto);
```

returns `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Using Jquery: Have a look at this question: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1)

You should replace

```
document.getElementById("photo").value = fileName;
```

by

```
$scope.uploadPhoto = fileName;
```

Short explanation : If you update an angular variable (eg : `document.getElementById("photo").value = fileName;`), angular won't know that you did it. There is worse with your code. For Angular, what's in `$scope` is his "trusted data source". Which means that Angular could also erase the value you put by using Jquery.

Comment: So curious. Thank you! Worked for me.